# Accessing a JSON Object's key values

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, javascript-objects

I am stuck.  It seems that this should be working, but it is not.

I am trying to access an object's key values, but it is not working.  I've done this before and have read plenty of things here on stack overflow and elsewhere, but it still does not work.

Here is my code:

```
  var validate = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  
  Logger.log('validate = ' + validate);
  Logger.log("validate['response'] = " + validate["response"]);
  Logger.log('validate.response = ' + validate.response);
  Logger.log("validate.['done'] = " + validate["done"]);
  Logger.log("validate.done = " + validate.done);
  
  var validateObj = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(validate));
  
  Logger.log("validateObj = " + validateObj);
  Logger.log("validateObj.response = " + validateObj.response);
  Logger.log("validateObj.done = " + validateObj.done);
```

and here are the logs:

```
validate = {
  "done": true,
  "response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse",
    "result": "Invalid Full Name.  Please enter a valid Full Name."
  }
}

validate['response'] = undefined

validate.response = undefined

validate.['done'] = undefined

validate.done = undefined

validateObj = {"done":true,"response":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse","result":"Invalid Full Name.  Please enter a valid Full Name."}}

validateObj.response = undefined

validateObj.done = undefined
```

When using bracket notation, I've tried using single and double quotes as well.

Can anyone help me to see the error?

Comment: `validate` is not deserialized

Comment: what is the result if you console.log(JSON.stringify(validate)); after var validate = ...

Comment: I've tried other variable names as well, such as my own first name.  Still the exact same results.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is basically the inverse operation of `JSON.parse`. You will therefore end up with the original value if you do  `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(validate))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the `response` and `done` property from a string, therefore you are getting `undefined`. You have tried to do `JSON.parse` on the response but then `JSON.stringify` it back to a string, just do `JSON.parse` and access the property

```
var validateObj = JSON.parse(validate); // Now you have a deserialized object

Logger.log("validateObj = " + validateObj); // You should get "validateObj = [object Object]"
Logger.log("validateObj.response = " + validateObj.response);
Logger.log("validateObj.done = " + validateObj.done);
Logger.log("validateObj[ 'response' ] = " + validateObj[ 'response' ] );
Logger.log("validateObj[ 'done' ]= " + validateObj[ 'done' ]);
```